# How to transform the data from one format to another format

Tags: android, string, dataformat

I have my date in this format `yyyy-mm-dd` and I save the date in this format as a String. Now I have the String and I want to know how can I get `yyyy`, `mm` or `dd` in 3 different String.

Comment: Did you tried DateFormat here is [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Comment: I don't have DateFormat, I have a String : String data="2011-06-15" something like that...and I need 2011,06 and 15 in 3 differents String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that every single time it will be in that same format you can do a string split on that string, and get the values from the resulting array.

```
String date = "2011-06-15";

String[] dates = date.split("-");

String year = dates[0];
String month = dates[1];
String day = dates[2];
```

This won't work if your date ends up in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "2011-06-15";
String[] strings = data.split("-");
// strings[0] = "2011"
// strings[1] = "06"
// strings[2] = "15"
```